# When does $R [x]/I $ have infinitely many idempotents in special case?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

At < [When does $R [x]/I $ has infinitely many idempotents?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219864/when-does-r-x-i-have-infinitely-many-idempotents) >, Er_Ro asked the following question.

> Let $R $ be a commutative ring with identity and $R[x] $ its polynomial ring. I am looking for a ring with finitely many idempotent and an unextended ideal $I $ in $R [x] $ such that $R[x]/I$ has infinitely many idempotent?

It is important and whenever $R $ is a semilocal non Notherian ring, I want to know that is there any example in this case.

Comment: I guess this is the best way for you to do this as you cannot comment on the Er_Ro question or answer.